# Fredholm alternative theorem for matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ symmetric and $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

How I can prove that if $b\perp \ker A$ then there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=b$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : Since the matrix is symmetric it has an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors. The kernel is the eigenspace for $0$ and the image is the sum of all other eigenspaces.